# Good Newsgroup Client for OS X

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, snow-leopard

I've just switched to OS X and am struggling to find a good, easy to use, and preferably free/cheap newsgroup reader. Does anyone have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unison](https://panic.com/unison/) is very nice and freely available (but [not actively developed](http://www.panic.com/blog/the-future-of-unison/)). [OSXnews](https://sourceforge.net/projects/osxnews/) may not be as polished as Unison, but it works and it is open source.

Answer (score 9):

Unison by Panic is quite good. It's fully featured and looks nice but the UI is a bit wonky at times.

https://panic.com/unison/

Answer (score 2):

"Cheap" is a relative and subjective term, but if you want good, then I highly recommend [Unison by Panic Software](http://panic.com/unison/).

Answer (score 1):

[SeaMonkey](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/) is pretty good and it is for free. It is a Firefox-based all-in-one internet suite application featuring a web-browser as well as e-mail, newsgroup, IRC and RSS clients, but it can be set up to only display the newsgroup reader on startup in the preferences under "Appearance".

Answer (score 1):

I use [MacSoup](http://www.haller-berlin.de/macsoup/) on Lion. It appears dated and some functions like filtering are not as easy to use as they could be, also it can only deal with one newsserver. It also can't show non text news e.g. MIME However it has a very good way of displaying and managing threads which outways its limitations

MacSoup is 32 bit only and so only runs on OSX up to Mojave. So I will be back to gnus in emacs.